# How do I close a presentation created from a template and then make a pdf out of it?

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf, google-slides

I am creating google slides from google sheets. I've succeeded in creating the slides but now I need to convert them to pdf so I can send them out to different people. From what I read, I am supposed to close the slide presentation before making the pdf. I tried using saveAndClose but I get the error

> saveAndClose is not a function

Here is the code.

```
function generateCerts() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('the spreadsheet');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var templateId = 'the template';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('the folder');

  // some other code

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var templateCopy = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy(folder);
    var slide = SlidesApp.openById(templateCopy.getId()).getSlides()[0];
    var shapes = slide.getShapes();

    // the slides are created in this loop

    var certificateName = school + "_Certificate";
    templateCopy.setName(certificateName);

    templateCopy.saveAndClose();
    var certBlob = templateCopy.getAs('application/pdf').setName(certificateName + '.pdf');
    folder.createFile(certBlob);
  }
}
```

I have tried separating them into two functions but what happened was I got several PDF copies of the template I used to create the slides instead of the slides with the data already in them.

Someone please tell me what I did wrong and how am I supposed to do this.

Comment: As Tanaike in the previous post hinted, `templateCopy` is not a `Presentation`. You get it when you `openById`. You should `saveAndClose` what was returned by  (``openById()``)

Comment: See [how to accept](/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- `saveAndClose()` is a method of Class Presentation. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#saveAndClose()) But, in your script, `templateCopy` is Class File. I think that this is the reason for your current issue of `saveAndClose is not a function`. This has also been mentioned in TheMaster's comment. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77414063/how-do-i-close-a-presentation-created-from-a-template-and-then-make-a-pdf-out-of#comment136497501_77414063)
- In your showing script, `school` is not declared. Please be careful about this.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function generateCerts() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('the spreadsheet');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var templateId = 'the template';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('the folder');
  
  // some other code
  
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var templateCopy = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy(folder);
    var s = SlidesApp.openById(templateCopy.getId()); // Modified
    var slide = s.getSlides()[0]; // Modified
    var shapes = slide.getShapes();
    
    // the slides are created in this loop

    var certificateName = school + "_Certificate";
    templateCopy.setName(certificateName);

    s.saveAndClose(); // Modified
    var certBlob = templateCopy.getAs('application/pdf').setName(certificateName + '.pdf');
    folder.createFile(certBlob);
  }
}
```

- In this modification, it supposes that `school` has already been declared elsewhere. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [saveAndClose() of Class Presentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#saveAndClose())

Comment: Thank you very much, these info are helpful. I just learned that I can open a file as a File and as a Slide presentation at the same time. This worked, finally.

Comment: @Geb Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.